# Ensure security for Inbound Emails Salesforce

Tags: email, email2case, inboundservices

How can we ensure protection for Inbound Emails. How can we ensure protection against Viruses in inbound email messages(Setup using Email Services).

Can we setup some scanning for attachments in inbound Emails. Or is there a default security check adopted in salesforce to scan the incoming messages.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link. http://www.datamotion.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/DM_DataSheet_SecureMail_Salesforce.pdf

DataMotion™ SecureMail for Salesforce enables any user of
Salesforce.com Enterprise Edition to send secure, trackable emails – including
attachments – from inside the Salesforce application.